Why is there a data-saferedirecturl added to some backlinks but not all?
I've noticed that some of the backlinks I've inserted into my articles have added code for a data-saferedirecturl= and I don't know why.
Inspect code block
Our blog is hosted on HubSpot but the URL added to data-saferedirecturl= is from Google.
I've read about what this is but only in the context of links added to emails. I haven't found anything related to it happening on a blog article webpage.
I've tried various links and some have it added and some don't.
I've looked for the following correlations with no clear answer:
Site DR
Organic traffic
Age of site
Age of webpage
Author

This doesn't seem to be a coding question. Please see the [help]. You may want to ask on a HubSpot support forum.
